# Unable to Import the Tweepy Module to Python

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, tweepy

I installed tweepy 3.60 via the command prompt in windows 7.
I opened Python IDLE (2.7.10) and tried to import tweepy but I get the following error message:
ImportError: No module named tweepy.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: You may have installed Tweepy for Python 3, and not for Python 2?

Comment: How would I find this out? I downloaded tweepy from here https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy. It says "Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 & 3.5 are supported."

Comment: Can't you use pip to install modules? It would be safer.

Comment: Can you please advise how I could install tweepy via pip? I am quite new to all of this.

Comment: I do not use Windows, but I guess that if you have pip installed, `pip install tweepy` in the command line should do what you want. If not, you can have a look at the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/installing/).

Comment: To make absolutely sure that this has nothing to do with IDLE (which I am sure it does not), run python directly either from the installed icon or with `py -2.7`.  Then enter `import tweepy` at the `>>>` prompt.  When you downloaded tweepy, where did you put it?  In the 2.7 site-packages?

Comment: I entered import tweepy from IDLE (GUI Interface) as you suggested and I got the same error message. When I downloaded tweepy I placed the file on my desktop. I followed the instructions of this youtuber to install tweepy - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUUxmvvl2FE. I am not sure if my Python folder has site-packages? The folder structure for me looks as follows C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4